# How to setup GeoWebCache to produce same grid as GoogleMaps?

Tags: google-maps, geowebcache

Is it possible to create gridSet in GeoWebCache which has same number of zoomlevels with scaleDenominators compatible with google maps?

There is EPSG:4326 default, but no mention of number of zoomlevels/scaleDenominators in documentation.

Comment: It also comes with 900913 as a default - does that not give you the same layout as Google Maps?

Comment: Well, number of zoom levels is different.

Comment: You'll probably need to add a zoom offset parameter to your client applications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GeoWebCache can not match with Google Maps on zoomlevels, One thing need to understand that, Google Maps still donot have unique zoom level support for globe. It differs based on location and map types. Google physical map(Terrain) not supporting zoom level more than 15. And location differs zoomlevel can be checked : http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/maxzoom-simple.html

And note that GeoWebcache should not use for Google Maps caching purpose. So, Other overlays only used by GeoWebcache. And GeoWebcache allows to generate cache for required zoom levels as pre-seed or can be done on-the-fly.

If you don't want to generate tile cache for level where Google Maps didn't support. It is possible to use on-the-fly cache generation mechanism and client side use Google Maps JS API to check for zoomlevel support as similar to example link given in this answer and control map not loaded to that level, then GeoWebcache will not generate too.