# Using GeoWebCache to cache Google maps tiles

Tags: geoserver, google-maps, tiles, tilecache, geowebcache

I'm new to GIS and I would like to know if anybody could give me a quick example of using GeoWebCache with Google maps tiles.

Answer (score 1):

check these links:

http://geowebcache.org/docs/current/services/gmaps.html

[How to setup GeoWebCache to produce same grid as GoogleMaps?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7662/how-to-setup-geowebcache-to-produce-same-grid-as-googlemaps)

http://fuzzytolerance.info/blog/google-earth-api-integration-via-geowebcache/

Hope these links will help you.